# Combining all data in table into one large column?

Tags: powerquery

I am working in Excel's Power Query Editor and currently have a table that is 29 cells long and x cells tall.

I need every single value of each cell to become its own cell in one long column(or row).

The problem is the height of the table will continually grow so I can't manually do this as it will ignore any new rows afterwords.

Anyone know a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Table.UnpivotOtherColumns` to unpivot everything, then remove the Attribute column:

```
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Columns",{"Attribute"})
```